# Multi-staged SQL query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using GCP public data and trying to analyse ads. Basically I'm trying to get the breakdown of the top 50 overall `advertiser_name` for all the `country_subdivision_primary`.

Here is how to get the top 50 spenders (`advertiser_name`)

```sql
SELECT 
    sum(spend_gbp), 
    advertiser_name,

DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sum(spend_gbp) DESC NULLS LAST) as rnk

FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_political_ads.advertiser_geo_spend`

GROUP BY 
    advertiser_name

ORDER BY 
    sum(spend_gbp) DESC

LIMIT 50
```

Here is how to get the `advertiser_name` spending per `country_subdivision_primary`

```sql
SELECT 
    sum(spend_gbp), 
    advertiser_name,
    country_subdivision_primary

FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_political_ads.advertiser_geo_spend`

GROUP BY 
    advertiser_name,
    country_subdivision_primary

ORDER BY 
    sum(spend_gbp) DESC
```

The issue is I have no idea to to use the top 50 results from the first search to get second search to show me the top overall spenders breakdown per state (country_subdivision_primary)

On a smaller but related note, why can I not use `rnk <= 50` to filter the top 50? I get an error if I do this.

Comment: Are you using BigQuery or Postgres? You need maybe something like `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`. And you can only access the `rnk` column if you put it in a subquery

Comment: I'm using BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Edit*

Having re-read your question, I think I understand what you want. You are trying to get the full breakdown by `country_subdivision_primary` for the top 50 `advertiser_name`. So you just need to `PARTITION` your ranking, then filter it via a subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sum(spend_gbp) as total_spend, 
        advertiser_name,
        country_subdivision_primary,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_advertiser_spend DESC NULLS LAST) as rnk

    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            SUM(spend_gbp) OVER (PARTITION BY advertiser_name) AS total_advertiser_spend
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_political_ads.advertiser_geo_spend`
    ) t

    GROUP BY 
        advertiser_name, country_subdivision_primary, total_advertiser_spend
) t

WHERE rnk <= 50

ORDER BY 
    sum(spend_gbp) DESC
```

---

### Original answer:

`ROLLUP` should do the trick for you.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sum(spend_gbp) as total, 
        advertiser_name,
        country_subdivision_primary,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER
           (PARTITION BY advertiser_name, country_subdivision_primary
            ORDER BY sum(spend_gbp) DESC NULLS LAST) as rnk

    FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.google_political_ads.advertiser_geo_spend`

    GROUP BY ROLLUP(advertiser_name, country_subdivision_primary)

) t
WHERE rnk <= 50

ORDER BY 
    total DESC
```

In BigQuery, you must put this in a subquery to be able to access `rnk`.

What `ROLLUP` does is group the data multiple times, so you get for example:

| total | advertiser_name | country_subdivision_primary | rnk | *note* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50.0 | advertiser1 | NY | 1 |  |
| 25.0 | advertiser1 | NJ | 2 |  |
| 75.0 | advertiser1 | NULL | 1 | first level subtotal |
| 20.0 | advertiser2 | NY | 1 |  |
| 10.0 | advertiser2 | NJ | 2 |  |
| 30.0 | advertiser2 | NULL | 2 | first level subtotal |
| 80.0 | NULL | NULL | 1 | Grand total |

The `NULL`s represent the (sub)totals. If you don't want those you can filter them out in the outer `WHERE`, like `WHERE advertiser_name IS NOT NULL`.

Unfortunately BigQuery does not seem to support `GROUPING SETS`, which would have made things easier.

The rank is calculated on each grouping level separately.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Analytic function not allowed in HAVING clause at [14:8]` in BigQuery

Comment: Ok it's gotta go in a subquery

Comment: This is fantastic thank you. The issue is that I want the per state (`country_subdivision_primary`) values for the top 50 overall spenders. Currently the output is quite off. many of the states are null and the values are incorrect. There should be 50 advertisers x 51 states, which is 255 rows. Currently this is not the case.

Comment: Once I remove the `NULL` values from your code output, the output on your code looks identical to the second code snippet in my question. From your reply, I'm guessing there isn't really a way to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Basically I want the `country_subdivision_primary` breakdown (example of which is shown in my snippet 2 and also show in your edited code) for the top 50 `advertiser_name` (list of which is shown in my snippet 1). The reason I want the results only for those 50 (shown in snippet 1) is that those `advertiser_name` have had the highest overall spend. Your current edit code still shows the `country_subdivision_primary` breakdown for all the `advertiser_name`. Basically there should be 50 `advertiser_name` and 51 `country_subdivision_primary` for each. Therefore we should have 255 rows.